# Login to a network domain

Tags: networking, active-directory

I have a laptop which is dual boot with Windows XP and Ubuntu 10.10.
On Windows it always logs into the domain and I am able to connect to over 
ethernet since it is based on the domain.

However on my Ubuntu I use hostname as ubuntu which is default.
How do I ensure that it uses the same hostname and domain as in Windows.

Is there a way to migrate the settings from Windows?

Thanks
Madhava

Comment: "since it is based on the domain" Does this mean Active Directory machine account?

Comment: What domain?  Are you at home, work, school?

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool in the Ubuntu repositories called `likewise-open` that allows you to join an Ubuntu machine to a domain hosted by Active Directory. Once you join your machine to the domain, you can log in to Ubuntu using your domain account (although I have had to type in my full user name, DOMAIN/user, to get it to work properly).

You will need to have special "Domain Admin" privileges to join your computer, however; you may have to ask someone from your IT department to use their domain account if you don't have these.

Comment: Let me try this and see if it works.

Comment: This also didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

To change the hostname:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

Replace 'ubuntu' with the new hostname. Save. Reboot.
And for the domain name...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

which might look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

192.168.1.100 your-host.your-domain.com your-host
```

Comment: Tried it didn't work, I want to ensure that the domain name is set properly so that I am able to connect to my Corporate network over Ethernet.

Comment: I added changing the domain name.

Comment: Somehow the domainname is not getting updated at all.

Comment: Any solutions? I still haven't been able to get to domainname to set properly at all.

Comment: Does the machine need to join with Active Directory? Or is that line of thinking totally out?